# sharepoint 2010 retrieve Lookup column by typing

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a SP list that uses a lookup from another list. this other list is very long and want to have a way to type the letter W for example, then it gives me the values that start with W.  I am using Desinger. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://www.directsharepoint.com/2011/03/implementing-type-ahead-search-using.html) shows how it can be done. However it is dependent on some developer level experience.

Comment: Any other ways. This seems to be for doc lib. I need it for a lookup sublist.

Comment: This is not specific to a doclib. Change the field searched ('FileLeafRef') to what you want to find

Answer (score 0):

if you are editing an item and need to select a value from list that has lots of items, then you can type any letter in the select control, but you have to use IE.